# How to use Mann-Whitney U test in learning

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a table (X, Y) where X is a matrix and Y is a vector of classes. Here an example:

```
X = 0 0 1 0 1   and Y = 1
    0 1 0 0 0           1
    1 1 1 0 1           0
```

I want to use Mann-Whitney U test to compute the feature importance(feature selection)

```
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
results = np.zeros((X.shape[1],2))
for i in xrange(X.shape[1]):
    u, prob = mannwhitneyu(X[:,i], Y)
    results[i,:] = u, pro
```

I'm not sure if this is correct or no? I obtained large values for a large table, `u = 990` for some columns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think that using Mann-Whitney U test is a good way to do feature selection. Mann-Whitney tests whether distributions of the two variable are the same, it tells you nothing about how correlated the variables are. For example:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
>>> a = np.arange(100)
>>> b = np.arange(100)
>>> np.random.shuffle(b)
>>> np.corrcoef(a,b)
   array([[ 1.        , -0.07155116],
          [-0.07155116,  1.        ]])
>>> mannwhitneyu(a, b)
(5000.0, 0.49951259627554112) # result for almost not correlated
>>> mannwhitneyu(a, a)
(5000.0, 0.49951259627554112) # result for perfectly correlated
```

Because `a` and `b` have the same distributions we fail to reject the null hypothesis that the distributions are identical.

And since in features selection you are trying find features that mostly explain `Y`, Mann-Whitney U does not help you with that.

Comment: seems like there is a problem with result in last line, shouldn't it be pvalue=1 ?

Comment: As from the scipy doc: "Defaults to None, which results in a p-value half the size of the ‘two-sided’ p-value and a different U statistic." (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html)

Comment: "Mann-Whitney tests whether distributions of the two variable are the same"


I think you're thinking of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) Test. The Mann-Whitney U Test tests whether a randomly chosen sample from one distribution will be greater (or less than) a randomly chosen sample from another distribution.